# How to receive a out parameter(sys_refcursor) of stored procedure Oracle in Django

Tags: python, django, oracle, stored-procedures, cx-oracle

I have created a stored procedure **usuarios_get** , I test it in oracle console and work fine. This is the code of stored procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE USUARIOS_GET(
text_search     in VARCHAR2,
usuarios_list   out sys_refcursor
)  
AS
--Variables
BEGIN
open usuarios_list for select * from USUARIO
END USUARIOS_GET;
```

The python code is this:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    listado = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
    l_query = cursor.callproc('usuarios_get', ('',listado))  #in this sentence produces error
    l_results = l_query[1]
```

The error is the following:

> NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type VariableWrapper

I've also tried with other stored procedure with a out parameter number type and modifying  in python code **listado= cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)** and I get the same error

> NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type VariableWrapper

I work with

- python 2.7.12
- Django 1.10.4
- cx_Oracle 5.2.1
- Oracle 12c

Can any help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: check this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887714/django-returning-out-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-when-using-cursor-oracle/61915745#61915745

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Django's wrapper is incomplete. As such you need to make sure you have a "raw" cx_Oracle cursor instead. You can do that using the following code:

```
django_cursor = connection.cursor()
raw_cursor = django_cursor.connection.cursor()
out_arg = raw_cursor.var(int) # or raw_cursor.var(float)
raw_cursor.callproc("<procedure_name>", (in_arg, out_arg))
out_val = out_arg.getvalue()
```

Then use the "raw" cursor to create the variable and call the stored procedure.

Looking at the definition of the variable wrapper in Django it also looks like you can access the "var" property on the wrapper. You can also pass that directly to the stored procedure instead -- but I don't know if that is a better long-term option or not!

Comment: what if the cursor return value is array ??? This will work for that scenario.. ??

Comment: Yes, it should.

Answer (score 2):

Anthony's solution works for me with Django 2.2 and Oracle 12c.  Thanks!  Couldn't find this solution anywhere else on the web.

```
dcursor = connection.cursor()
cursor = dcursor.connection.cursor()
import cx_Oracle
out_arg = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
ret = cursor.callproc("<procedure_name>", (in_arg, out_arg))
```

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include the additional code you put in yours, but with further simplifications. Hopefully now a one-stop shop!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much I was scrolling all over the internet didn't find any solution above solution worked for me

```
import cx_Oracle

    def call_stored_procedure():
    conn =  cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@host:port/service_name")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Call the stored procedure
    out_cursor = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
    cursor.callproc("your_stored_proc_name", (out_cursor,))

    # Fetch the result from the cursor
    result = out_cursor.getvalue().fetchall()

    # Close cursor and connection
    out_cursor.close()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return result
```