# Django, returning out parameters of a stored procedure when using cursor (Oracle)

Tags: python, django

I have written the below function to simplify the way i call stored procedures. I need help on how to return the out parameters.

```
def call_procedure(dbname,procedure_name,parameters_list=[]):
    with connections[dbname].cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            cursor.callproc(procedure_name, parameters_list)
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(e)
```

Procedure call:

`call_procedure('testdb',[1,2,3,''])`

In the call I need to print the out parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django lacks important information in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.CursorWrapper.callproc).

For detail explanation,about PL/SQL execution (Oracle DB), check [this link](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html) in the cx_Oracle docs page

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
   outVal = cursor.var(int).var
   cursor.callproc('myproc', [123, outVal])
   print(outVal.getvalue())        # will print 246
```

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure myproc (
    a_Value1                            number,
    a_Value2                            out number
) as
begin
    a_Value2 := a_Value1 * 2;
end;
```